# adding an additional link to the wp_pages_dropdown menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, select, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a wordpress theme that uses dropdowns for part of the site navigation.

I'm using wp_pages_dropdown and wp_dropdown_categories to output my menus as a dropdown jump menu, this is all good,works fine, but I would like to add a 'home' link to the end of the list of `<option>'s`

I have been having a go at it - my html/css is spotless but I am not a programmer, can any one help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

`<?php wp_dropdown_pages('show_option_none=Select Page');?>`

`<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select Category'); ?>`

I am thinking that I need to somehow work `<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>` into it somehow. Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Are you appending Home to the Dropdown list? I think the best fit would be to go into the function and append your option there.

Comment: Hi Anraiki, 

Yes appending it is exactly what I had in mind. 

Going into the function means editing the WordPress core files am I correct?

Comment: yes, and you don't want to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the simplest approach is to just filter the output of `wp_dropdown_...` and inject your option just before the closing `select` tag;

```
function insert_home_in_dropdown($output)
{
    $end = '<option value="whatever">Home</option></select>';
    return preg_replace('#</select>$#', $end, trim($output)); 
}
add_filter('wp_dropdown_pages', 'insert_home_in_dropdown');
```

Comment: Hey, well I went ahead and edited the post-template.php file and tweaked my jump menu js and got it working but yours is a much more elegant solution, thankyou.

For clarification for viewers who know even less than me I have added a more detailed explanation below (or possibly above).

thanks TDM, thats really excellent.

Answer (score 0):

My code looks like this, and in my functions.php code I edited the value to be 0.

```
    var dropdownf = document.getElementById("page_id");
                function onPageChange() {
                if ( dropdownf.options[dropdownf.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?page_id="+dropdownf.options[dropdownf.selectedIndex].value;
                    }

                if ( dropdownf.options[dropdownf.selectedIndex].value == 0 ) {
                location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"; // this give the href to the home link 
                    }

                }
                dropdownf.onchange = onPageChange;
```