# Dropdown menu default value

Tags: php, function, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu of pages, but after I go to a page selected, let's say "About us", the default title button of dropbown is the title of the page, "About us", so i want the title/default option to be "Please select a page" or something like that.

My code is this:

```
wp_dropdown_pages("title_li=&depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&selected=$currPage");
```

What i'm doing wrong or how my code should look?

Comment: This could probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335706/adding-an-additional-link-to-the-wp-pages-dropdown-menu-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
wp_dropdown_pages("title_li=&depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&selected=Please select a page");
```

Comment: thank you for reply, this doesn't work like it should, now the default value is the first element, which is a page and I don't see "Please select a page" element in my dropdown